# How to create columns using values from one column in SQL (PROC SQL in SAS)

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I am using PROC SQL on SAS.

The table on the left is the one I have. I want to create the table on the right, i.e creating as many columns as there are different values for the column 'value' (they are known and only 3 of them : "a", "b" and "c").

The value is the one from "col". If it doesn't exist for corresponding 'value', default value is 0. I tried using GROUP BY and CASE, but I still wound up with a table with 6 lines.

[image: Tables]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In SAS, you can use `proc sql`:

```
proc sql;
    select id,
           sum(case when value = 'a' then col else 0 end) as col_a,
           sum(case when value = 'b' then col else 0 end) as col_b,
           sum(case when value = 'c' then col else 0 end) as col_c
    from t
    group by id;
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked (with a SELECT DISTINCT ; without it I still had 6 observations instead of 3).

Comment: @PizzaKebab . . . That is curious.  The `group by` should take care of that.

Comment: Yep you're right, I ran it again and it worked just fine without the DISTINCT. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**`proc_transpose`**](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=p1r2tjnp8ewe3sn1acnpnrs3xbad.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) which is dynamic to any length of values:

```
** TRANSPOSING DATA SET;
proc sort data=input out=input;
    by id;
run;

proc transpose data=input out=input_transposed(drop=_name_) prefix=col_;
    by id;          
    var col;    
    id value;
run;
```

[image: SAS Output]

To replace missing for zeros run across arrays of numeric columns to call [`coalesce`](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=p1gdr5t7sd3g3qn1d7fg23zuwzml.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en). Again, this scales to hundreds of potential columns:

```
data input_transposed;
    set input_transposed;

    array num(*) _numeric_;
    do _n_ = 1 to dim(num);
    num(_n_) = coalesce(num(_n_), 0);
end;
```

[image: SAS Table Output]